# Нужна ли выделенная запятая?

Tags: запятые, уточнения

Нужна ли здесь выделенная запятая? Это уточнение?

> Возиться с этой сногсшибательной, но чересчур прямолинейной(,) дамой
> приходится руководителю отдела, Энтони Джонсу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не нужна. Там нет нужды в уточнении. Ещё вот в чём дело: "возиться" указывает на что-то негативное, и это негативное нельзя кидать в уточнение, во вставку с тире, в скобки, чтобы при изъятии конструкции не нарушался смысл.

Розенталь:
После последнего однородного члена предложения, присоединяемого противительным или подчинительным союзом и не заканчивающего собой предложения, запятая не ставится (т. е. последний однородный член не обособляется):
*Не род, а ум поставлю в воеводы.

Каждый вечер солнце садилось в море, а не в тучи и было при этом клюквенного цвета.

**Они получили небольшую, но удобную квартиру.**

Поставлена трудная, зато интересная задача.

Слышалась жалобная, если не униженная просьба пощадить его самолюбие.

В кинофильме рассказывается о первой, пусть неразделённой любви.

Получены важные, хотя и не итоговые сведения.

У девочки опасная, потому что заразная болезнь.*
http://old-rozental.ru/paragraph.php?file=pt_12.htm

Comment: Спасибо за развёрнутый ответ.