# "Он привык пить не чай, а кофе(,) и оттого бегать как наскипидаренный". Нужна ли выделенная запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

> Он привык пить не чай, а кофе(,) и оттого бегать как наскипидаренный.

Что-то я затупил и не могу понять, какой член предложения "а кофе" и нужно ли в моём случае выделять его запятыми с обеих сторон.

Comment: Эх, надо было ему моего кофе попить!

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/467839

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно: *Он привык пить **не чай, а кофе** и оттого бегать как наскипидаренный.*

1. Запятая не ставится, о чем говорится у Розенталя:  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=100#pp100

Пункт 6. После последнего однородного члена предложения, присоединяемого **противительным** или подчинительным союзом и не заканчивающего собой предложения, запятая **не ставится** (т. е. последний однородный член не обособляется): Не род, а ум поставлю в воеводы (П.); *Каждый вечер солнце садилось **в море, а не в тучи** и было при этом клюквенного цвета* (Ю. К.);

2. Грамматическая основа: Он привык пить и оттого бегать. Однородные отношения между инфинитивами, при этом они дифференцированы наречием ОТТОГО со значение причины.

Пить *не чай, а кофе* – однородные дополнения с противопоставлением.

3. Примечание по стилистике. А если так: *Он привык пить не чай, а кофе и оттого бегал как наскипидаренный.*

Comment: Блин, я же даже выписывал в памятку пример про "в море, а не в тучи". Но всё равно забыл. Спасибо. // По стилистике ваш вариант корректен, конечно, а мой нет, но это предложение просто пример, на скорую руку сляпанный)

Comment: Хорошо сочиняете, прямо в стиле Достоевского. Я даже проверила текст в поисковике. а то начнешь еще классиков критиковать... :)